# IIS Website in Docker starting as "Stopped"

Tags: asp.net, powershell, docker, iis, windows-server-2016

I'm using the `microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1` to host ASP.NET MVC inside a docker container, but I also **need** SSL, so I've added the binding as the container starts

The container starts fine, but on looking at the IIS Website, it's marked as `Stopped`.

I can't see anything in the event logs, to help out, trying to `Start-Website -name "Site"` just gives the below error. I tried removing the default website, and putting mine in it's place, but that also errors.

I have a `Remove-Website` in there, but this is still not removed.

```
Start-Website : Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B7)
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Website -Name "Site"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Website], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.StartWebsiteCommand
```

Running Websites

```
PS C:\inetpubwwwroot> Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites

Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------
Site             8374 Stopped    C:\inetpub\wwwroot             http *:8080:
                 4692                                           http *:443:
                 9
```

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709

RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command \
    Import-module IISAdministration; \
    Remove-Website -Name *; 

RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command New-IISSite -Name "Site" -PhysicalPath C:\inetpub\wwwroot -BindingInformation "*:8080:"; \
    New-WebBinding -Name "Site" -IPAddress "*" -Port 443 

WORKDIR /inetpub\wwwroot
COPY ./bin/Debug/PublishOutput .
```

Comment: You must also give the container a certificate via HTTP API. Learn `netsh http`.

Comment: What's netsh http?